# How to check If a Tel: area code is correct using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy
I need to check if the given phone area code is correct.
i created a input field, user can insert a tel area code like **0044** oder **0090** and so on.
I restricted the input field to 4 chars. 
I need to check after the 4 chars are entered if the area code is correct.

**What it should do.**
After entering **4** number, the script should check the following things.
Does the entered number equals something like  `"00{number 2 digit only}"` if it doesnt `alert("please enter correct tel areacode");`

I hope i could explain my problem clear. 
How can i do it with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Are you assuming 00 means international? If so (area codes are usually domestic), what about US/Canada (which is just '1')

Comment: Yes i mean tel usualy something like 0090 for turkey ...

Comment: Note that `00` is *not* a global convention for international calls, it is used for them in most countries but not in all. The usual prefix to the country code would be `+` as in `+41 56 464 ......` for a number in Switzerland, or `+90 212  ...` for a number in Istanbul.

Comment: Yes i also need to check if it beginns with +90 if so i need to convert it to 0090

Comment: `00` is used in most countries for international dialling, but USA/Canada uses `001`. France has a choice of `00` or `19`. And other countries also differ. Some require you to dial a code and then wait for the dialling tone to resume before dialling further. `+` is the only safe bet.

Comment: +1 for `+`! There are many more possible IDD prefixes than just `00`, as well as many, *many* country codes that aren't two digits. Trying to ‘validate’ phone numbers is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "0000" a valid area code? It has "00" followed by two digits... but I assume the codes are 00 then a number 10 or higher.

```
$('input.phone').keyup( function(){
  var num = $(this).val(), i = parseInt(num, 10), valid = true;
  if(num.length==4 && (i<9 || i>99) ){
    //phone number is invalid
  }
});
```

But I think that blur event will  be more useful here, because the above function wouldn't notify the user if he typed only three digits. Notification will appear as soon as the focus is moved aout of the input box, not as soon as the fourth digit was typed. So my proposition is:

```
$('input.phone').blur( function(){
  var num = $(this).val(), i = parseInt(num, 10), valid = true;
  if(num.length != 4 || i<9 || i>99 ){
    //phone number is invalid, notify the user
  }
});
```

**edit**: I thought you're validating some kind of area codes specific to your coutry. If you want to validate international calling codes you may wish to look at this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes - there are many +XXX (or 00XXX) numbers and these won't fit into your 4 characters long input. And many numers aren't in +XX (00XX) format, like +1 (001) for USA. I think you should just check if it's + or 00 followed by at least one digit other than zero and let it in.

```
/^(\+|00)[1-9]/.test( input.value );
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$('#field').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    // Restrict length to 4 characters
    if(value.length > 4) {
        value = value.substring(0, 3);
        $(this).val(value);
    }

    // Test is value equals to "00{number 2 digit only}"
    if(/00\d{2}/.test(value)) {
        // Is valid
    } else {
        // Not valid
    }
});
```

I'd avoid using `alert` on the not valid part, as that would give the user an alert box every time he presses a key.